# Rabbitmq - Docker connection refused on port 5672

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq, docker-network

I have a web server written in Go that interacts with Rabbitmq and Mongodb. When I run all these servers on my machine without containers (rabbitmq url: `amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672`) it works fine.

Now I am trying to run all these services in a separate container. Here is my compose file

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
  web:
    build: .
    image: palash2504/collect
    container_name: collect-server
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - mongodb
    links: ["rabbitmq", "mongodb"]

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: collect-net
```

This is my servers dockerfile

```
FROM golang

ENV GO111MODULE=on


WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .

RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build

EXPOSE 3000


ENTRYPOINT ["/app/social-cops-assignment"]
```

My server can't seem to connect to rabbitmq. This is the log message I get when running `docker compose up` and the rabbitmq url in my config being `amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672` (since the container name is rabbitmq I replace localhost with rabbitmq so that my server is able to find the rabbitmq container)

```
collect-server | 2019/03/10 08:50:51 Failed to connect to AMQP compatible broker at: amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672/, with errror: dial tcp 172.24.0.3:5672: connect: connection refused
```

But rabbitmq seems to be ready to accept connections. These are the last two lines of the rabbitmq logs from `docker-compose up`

```
rabbitmq    | 2019-03-10 08:50:55.164 [info] <0.489.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.489.0> (172.24.0.4:49784 -> 172.24.0.3:5672)
rabbitmq    | 2019-03-10 08:50:55.205 [info] <0.489.0> connection <0.489.0> (172.24.0.4:49784 -> 172.24.0.3:5672): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
```

I am new to docker-networking and I don't know what am I doing wrong? Is it the rabbitmq address that I am using or I need some additional configuration with respect to rabbitmq or expose some ports?

Comment: can you execute `docker-compose restart web` and check if the issue still exist ? just make sure you don't restart rabbitmq

Comment: yes it still exists

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When targeting services, dont append a port. Use `rabbitmq`, not `rabbitmq:5672`.

I already answered this in your question here: [How to connect to rabbitmq container from the application server container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55077073/how-to-connect-to-rabbitmq-container-from-the-application-server-container)

All the docker network configuration (after the described fix above) seems to be fine. The remaining error is likely due to authentication issues related to your source code and/or authentication data/setup.

Comment: did that. replaced the rabbitmq url in my config file with this `amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq` but it still doesn't connect. Here is the error log `Failed to connect to AMQP compatible broker at: amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq/, with errror: dial tcp 172.24.0.2:5672: connect: connection refused`

Comment: What library is printing that error? I can't find it on the web, except for a blog post where it is included as an example.

Comment: I am using the go library for amqp https://godoc.org/github.com/streadway/amqp

This log message is from my application code but the last part is from the library `dial tcp 172.24.0.2:5672: connect: connection refused`

Comment: `connection refused` is likely related to authentication, not networking. I've added this to my answer.

Comment: I have had a similar problem due to an @ character in the login and password.

Answer (score 3):

Two things that fixed it for me:

1. Make sure not to use localhost, instead use the container's name. For me it was `amqp`.

```
amqp:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
```

Then the connection string will be `amqp://guest:guest@amqp/`.